"REST resource class not found" error in custom module
I'm developing a custom Drupal module called "Chatbot" that includes a REST resource. However, when I try to clear the cache using drush cr, I'm encountering the following error:
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase" not found in /var/www/html/web/modules/custom/chatbot/src/Plugin/rest/resource/ChatbotSettingsResource.php:21

Here are some details about my setup:

I've created a REST resource class ChatbotSettingsResource in my custom module.
The class is located at src/Plugin/rest/resource/ChatbotSettingsResource.php.
I've added a service definition in chatbot.services.yml.
The REST module is installed and enabled.

I've tried the following:

Clearing the cache (which is when I get the error)
Uninstalling and reinstalling my module

Here's a snippet of my ChatbotSettingsResource class:
namespace Drupal\chatbot\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

/**
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "chatbot_settings",
 *   label = @Translation("Chatbot Settings"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/chatbot/settings"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ChatbotSettingsResource extends ResourceBase {
  // Class implementation...
}

Can anyone help me understand why Drupal can't find the ResourceBase class, and how I can resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What is the service definition you added?  Rest resources do not need a service definition, and adding one is probably causing the failure.

Drupal plugins are not services. They are simply classes that use a specific annotation (before Drupal 10.3) or a specific PHP attribute (starting from Drupal 10.3).
